# Create a DIV at click; Then remove same DIV by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new to programming and particularly JS and JQuery.

I've searched SO for hours trying to figure out how to do this seemingly simple task and observed plenty of code from talented programmers, but nothing what would suit my request.

I'm simply trying to 
(A) create a dynamic DIV at the point on the page where the user clicks the mouse. This part I can accomplish.

(B) The next step is clicking on that new DIV and removing it from the page.

Here's what I've found to accomplish step A:

```
$(function(){
  $('#picture').click(function(e){
      var x = e.pageX - 20 + 'px';
      var y = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';
      var div = $('<div>', {
                            'class':'face',
                            'css': {
                            'position':'fixed',                    
                            'left': x,
                            'top': y,
                            'width': '40px',
                            'height': '40px'
                           },

              });


      $(document.body).append(div);
```

This simply creates a small 40x40px DIV in the body of the document.

Step B is proving beyond my knowledge. Simply being able to click on that newly created DIV and remove it from the document?

If I create the same div manually prior to the page loading, I can click it as expected. I just cant find a way to 'find' the newly created DIV's. Please help. I have researched extensively, and cant seem to find out how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/peyeze/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Use dynamic event delegation with the `.on()` method

```
$("body").on("click", ".face", function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(function(){
         $(this).remove();
     });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

P.S: to prevent dispatching events all over the document or `"body"` use rather the first static parent ID as selector `$("#someid").on`.

or as Santiago suggested (but slightly different), accessing the `"click"` Element property and not using the `div` variable at all:

```
  $('#picture').click(function(e) {

      var x = e.pageX - 20 + 'px';
      var y = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';

      $('<div />', { // Don't forget closign slash!
        'click': function(){ // The click property
          $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).remove();
          });
        },
        'class':'face',
        'css': {
          position: 'fixed',                    
          left: x,
          top: y,
          width: 40,
          height: 40
        }
      }).appendTo("body");

  });
```

***[jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/peyeze/6/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.face', function(){
     $(this).remove();
});
```

```js
$(function(){
        $('#picture').click(function(e){
            var x = e.pageX - 20 + 'px';
            var y = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';
            var div = $('<div/>', {
                'class':'face',
                'css': {
                    'position':'fixed',                    
                    'left': x,
                    'top': y,
                    'width': '40px',
                    'height': '40px'
                }
            });
            $(document.body).append(div);
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click','.face', function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

```css
#picture {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.face {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picture"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#picture').click(function(e) {
      var x = e.pageX - 20 + 'px';
      var y = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';
      var div = $('<div>', {
        'class':'face',
        'css': {
          'position':'fixed',                    
          'left': x,
          'top': y,
          'width': '40px',
          'height': '40px'
        },
        'click': function(ev) {
          $(ev.target).remove();
        }
      });
    $("body").append(div);
  });
});
```

```css
#picture {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background:gray;
  display:block;
}
.face {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picture"></div>
```

Comment: Or even simpler using `'click' : function` since you already accessed the Element Properties object: http://jsbin.com/peyeze/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually. Add a function to your javascript to remove the element after you create it. You can do it even more easily thanks to jQuery. I think that my answer is one of the most elegants here ;P hihi

```
div.click(function(){
          div.remove();
      });
```

I did a live example below, if you want to test it :)

```js
$(function(){
  $('#picture').click(function(e){
      var x = e.pageX - 20 + 'px';
      var y = e.pageY - 20 + 'px';
      var div = $('<div>', {
                            'class':'face',
                            'css': {
                            'position':'fixed',                    
                            'left': x,
                            'top': y,
                            'width': '40px',
                            'height': '40px'
                           },

              });
      
      /* HELLO DEAR, I DO THE TRICK */
      div.click(function(){
          div.remove();
      });

      $(document.body).append(div);
  });
});
```

```css
 #picture{
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   background-color:green;
   }

.face {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="picture">
  
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create the jQuery object first, then you can append and remove it at will, without creating a new jQuery object.

In the image click listener all the script below does is change the position of the square and append it if it isn't already appended, while clicking on the square itself will remove it.

```js
$(function(){
  var body = $('body');
  var div = $('<div>', {
    'class':'face',
    'css': {
      'position':'fixed', 
      'width': '40px',
      'height': '40px',
      'background': '#f9fd42',
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', function(e){
      if(div.is(e.target)) div.remove();
  });
  $('#demo').click(function(e){ 
    div.css({ 
      'left': e.pageX - 20 + 'px', 
      'top': e.pageY - 20 + 'px' 
    }).appendTo(body); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="//lorempixel.com/200/100" id="demo">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="full-page">
     <div class="imgbox">
    </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
    $('.imgbox').click(function(e){
    var x=e.pageX-20;
    var y=e.pageY-20;
    var ap_div='<div class="ap_div" style="left:'+ x +'px;top:'+ y+'px"></div>';
    $('.full-page').append(ap_div)});

  $('body').delegate(".ap_div", 'click', function(e){
    $(this).remove();
   });
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6czbzb38/2/